# I'm asking you to

Tags: tense, idiomatic-language

> This is crazy. So as your friend I'm asking you to stop.

Hi. Could anyone please tell me if the present continuous ("I'm asking") is completely correct and natural here if it's the first time he's asking the friend to stop whatever he's doing? Or would it only be natural if it's a repetition? As in the dialog below...

> Friend: You have to stop this.
>
> Guy: No, I don't.
>
> Friend: Yes, you do. This is crazy. So as your friend I'm asking you
> to stop.

Comment: What tense were you expecting to see there, and why?

Comment: "I'm asking" sounded natural to my ear but wasn't sure it was in this context. Besides that, I guess I would expect "I ask" or "I will ask". Would you find one of them more natural than the present continuous in this context?

Comment: All three are possible, but "I'm asking" is the most natural. "I ask" and "I will ask" both sound formal, like an official request, so they're inappropriate to say to a friend.

Answer (score 1):

This is natural.  The verb "ask" is in the present continuous because the process of asking is ongoing as the person is speaking.